# Using HTML to limit to appropriate decimal numbers but no letters

Tags: html, input, numbers, decimal

I have tried to use this code:

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || event.charCode == 46 || event.charCode == 0 ">
```

But sadly, this still allows 1567.5432.5678.4567 (multiple decimal points).

Is there a way to limit this to just 1 decimal point but unlimited decimal places or significant figures?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Regular Expression to use only numeric values and one decimal.

`^(\d+)?([.]?\d{0,2})?$`

If you want to use large scale (i.e. the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number) then change the number here \d{0,2}

Above expression allows the decimal digits between zero and 2 times.

Comment: Your regex is liming the decimal place number to two, he says unlimited number after the point.

Comment: `unlimited decimal places or significant figures`: The answer explains how to be flexible with it and increase or decerease the decimal scale.

Comment: Sorry, but the edit time is prior to the comment time.

Comment: Thanks... sadly (new to this) I actually don't know how to use this code yet. Where does this go to make an html input in a form only accept numbers with or without a decimal in it? Also, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression to to limit the decimal point.

`/\d+\.?\d*/`

E.g

`'123.675.009'.match(/\d+\.?\d*/)`

Returns 123.675

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this method:

```
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46)
        return false;
    return true;
    if (charCode === 46) {

    // Allow only 1 decimal point
    if ((element.value) && (element.value.indexOf('.') >= 0))
      return false;
    else
      return true;
  }
}
```

this works to solve the input of letters and more than one decimal place.